# MongoDB - Find elements that have the same value

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have data in the following format. It contains a document for each sales member and their number of sales for three days in an array.

```
{ "_id" : "Roger", "Sales" : [ 15, 2, 7 ] }
{ "_id" : "Sally", "Sales" : [ 11, 7, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : "Patrick", "Sales" : [ 3, 5, 9 ] }
{ "_id" : "Sarah", "Sales" : [ 9, 21, 11 ] }
{ "_id" : "Allen", "Sales" : [ 3, 9, 11 ] }
```

I would like to return the sales member name and sales for those who have the same number of sales for at least two of the three days. I would expect Sally, Sarah, Patrick, and Allen to be returned.

How can I do this? I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
db.SalesReport.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$Sales"},
  {"$group": {"$Name":"$Sales", "count":{"$sum":1}}},
  {"$match": {"count":{"$gt":1}}},
])
```

Comment: Why would you expect them? Because they all have an 11 in them? There seems to be some things missing from your explanation. Is this a homework question?

Comment: And you should also do `group` on `_id`: `{"$group": {"_id":"$Sales", "count":{"$sum":1}}}`

Comment: At the best I can see from your criteria, only "Roger" does not meet it in actual fact as all the others share "at least two sales figures" with someone else. You really need to explain yourself here because it does look like a homework problem, and there are completely different solutions to solving this on either a small or a "real world" scale

Comment: @Neil Lunn Yes, this is a problem I have been working on for a class final presentation, so a much smaller scale than in the real world. We have to present to the class how we would return the correct results, which are to return those who match on at least two of the three sales. You are correct that I missed Patrick and have edited that above.

Comment: I think your instructor wants you to solve this yourself. There is little point in you presenting something what somebody else solved for you. There is a logical course of action to the solution, and I'm guessing your instructor is presently trying to teach you something about complexity, given the different varying approaches.